# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre applicationContext y this en Kotlin usando un Toast.makeText()?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-context

He visto muchos desarrolladores usando el contexto, `applicationContext` o `this` en un `Toast` como lo muestra este código.

```
fun mostrarMensaje(){  Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Hola",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) }

fun mostrarMensaje2(){  Toast.makeText(this,"Hola",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) }
```

Cual es la diferencia entre this y applicationContext especificamente.

Comment: Obviamente, esto es una deficiencia del diseño de la API. En primer lugar, el contexto de la actividad y el contexto de la aplicación son objetos totalmente diferentes, por lo que los parámetros del método donde se usa el contexto deben usar ApplicationContext o Activity directamente, en lugar de usar la clase principal Context. En segundo lugar, el documento debe especificar qué contexto usar o no explícitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•  **Cuando usas `this`**:

```
fun mostrarMensaje2(){  Toast.makeText(this,"Hola",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) }
```

es porque **mediante `this` haces referencia a el contexto de la Actividad o a un servicio**, por lo tanto usas `this` para mostrar el `Toast` desde una `Activity` o un `Service`.

**• Cuando usas `applicationContext` :**

```
fun mostrarMensaje(){  Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Hola",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) }
```

indica que estas usando el contexto de la aplicación , similar a `getApplicationContext()` en Java.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El toast necesita un Context que usará para poder mostrarse.

this es la referencia a la Activity en la que se esta ejecutando, todos los Activity son ademas Context. por lo que estarias indicandole que el toast se muestre dentro del contexto de esa Activity.

El applicationContext es el contexto general de toda la aplicacion.

En la practica la diferencia entre usar uno u otro es casi indistinta, quizas la unica ventaja de usar applicationContext seria tener la certeza de que siempre sera un contexto valido. Mientras que si le pasas otro contexto podria ese contexto no serlo, aunque si usas this, forzosamente this existe sino no se estaria ejecutando ese codigo.